# How to implement Watchdog Reset in C

Tags: c, arm, keil, watchdog

I am trying to use watchdog Reset in an arm 7 processor (AT91R4008). Does anyone know how I should write the code in order to reset the processor by watchdog? Which libraries are necessary in Keil uVision 4.7?

Comment: If you want to test it, just go into a loop and stop feeding the dog, eventually, it will bark.   If you mean setting it up, why would you need any specific library?   It can't be that difficult, surely  Just write code for it: the control register addresses/contents are in the user manual for the device, no?   Note also that asking for libs is off-topic for SO.

Comment: Page 93 of the AT91R40008 reference (http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc1354.pdf) explains how to program it.  Basically, once you configure it to reset the processor when the timer expires and you enable it, you have to periodically restart the timer by writing `0xC071` to the `WD_CR` register.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks for your answer. If I just write: 'WD_CR = 0xC071;' is enough to reset the processor?

Comment: What?  I think you do not understand what you are doing.  Writing: 'WD_CR = 0xC071;' is enough to NOT reset the processor.

Comment: @MartinJames I didn't ask you...

Comment: @informaticien - yes, you did.  You posted on SO.  Michael was kind enough to actually do the user manual lookup that you should have done in the first place and even told you what to do, yet you still want more?

Comment: @MartinJames Your attitude is very offensive and I'm really sorry for you!! I have searched enough for this issue in so many forums and datasheets, and if I knew what to do I would never ask here. Remember, asking isn't crime!!!!

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks for your guidance. I did the 4 steps to enable the watchdog, and it works properly.